# How to remove fisheye distortion effect from image in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 want to remove the fisheye effect from the image. How do I remove that fisheye effect from the image or convert it into a simple image. I referred to some OpenCV site but couldn't find a solution. Is there any algorithm to do this in python. please help me. Thank you in advance.